# Separate number from string in smarty

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

I have a string like

```
$str ='my age is 100';
```

now I want to separate 100 from above string , how can I do so , using smarty

I am working on Prestashop. 
Thanks

Comment: Is there any logic behind this? Else I would just recommend you just $var = '100';

Comment: yeah i am getting that value from admin and i want to separate that number because i want to use that number somewhere else..

Comment: What I mean is, is it always that sentence, is it always last in the string, is there any logic here the number is in your string..

Comment: see @Naruto my string would be like                                 Include Couple Name (max 21 letters). Now i want to separate 21 from that string..did u get me this time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is only a number, you can just remove all non numeric characters from the string with a regular expression with [regex_replace](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.modifier.regex.replace.tpl):

```
{$str|regex_replace:"/[^0-9]/":""}
```

That will print 100 for the first example and 21 for the second. However it will not work fine for strings with different numbers, (i.e. "I have 2 cows and 1 rabbit" will return 21).

That all said, I advise you against extracting a number from a text string if you need it to use in your code, as it's prone to error. better declare a separate variable, instead

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that numbers in string are not followed or preceded by coma, brackets but just by spaces, you could use:

```
{assign var="str" value="my age is 100 Include Couple Name (max 21 letters)"}

{assign var="ar" value= " "|explode:$str}

{foreach $ar as $a}
    {if $a|is_numeric}
        {append var="numbers" value=$a}
    {/if}
{/foreach}

NUMBERS:<br />
{foreach $numbers as $n}
    {$n}<br />
{/foreach}
```

It will give output:

```
NUMBERS:
100
21
```

as expected.

Comment: @user3910051 Does my solution work for you? I saw you accepted it and unaccepted it later